# List manipulation leads to infinite loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, infinite-loop

I am trying to create an array for listing purposes in Ionic Framework and check all the callcenter name's first char to add them in an alphabet array.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < callcenterList.length; i++) {
    var value = callcenterList[i]._owner && callcenterList[i]._owner.company.name[0];

    if ((alphabet.indexOf(value) == -1 && isNaN(parseInt(value))) ||
      (isNaN(alphabet[0]) && !isNaN(value))) {
      if(!isNaN(value))
        value = 123;

      alphabet.push(value);

      callcenterList.splice(i, 0, {
        divider: {
          alphabet: value
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

Replacing `value = 123` with `value = '#'` causes Google Chrome and Google Chrome Canary to malfunction and immediately use up to 100% of RAM in Mac.

Is this a Javascript bug or is it related to Google Chrome itself?

Comment: Never heard of that one before...

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use double quotes rather than single?

Comment: Well, if it's #, then it's not part of the alphabet, and it's not a number, and since you limit your loop based on callcenterList.length (and push inside the loop) I don't think it has to do either with the # and neither with chrome? :)

Comment: @Icepickle isNaN('#') returns true. The problem is not related to changing value to 123 or # and whether it is a number or not. If I change value to ='AA', the problem doesnt appear.

Comment: @Yagiz, it's simply your fancy way of pushing an element into a list you are iterating that could cause serious problems, like the one you see here

Comment: @skobaljic Using array.length in for loop condition doesn't cause the browser to recalculate the array size again and again in each iteration.

Comment: @skobaljic since he is pushing at special indexes, he won't reach all indexes by taking the length before the loop starts. I would say, a copy of the list might be the simplest, safest solution to manipulate the data

Comment: @Yagiz Using array.length in for loop condition does cause the browser to recalculate/retrieve the array length on each iteration.

Comment: @Yagiz I changed the topic title and tags per this post http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254216/should-i-edit-titles-which-have-nothing-to-do-with-the-actual-problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't a bug in your browser or anything: you're just creating a condition where your code goes into an infinite loop, which always tends to make the browser seize up. You can do the same thing with a simple `while (true) {}` loop.

Specifically, you are iterating over the `callcenterList`, and any time `isNaN(alphabet[0])`, you are splicing a new element into `callcenterList`. `alphabet[0]` is going to have the first value that you push there which, in the conditional you're looking at, you're going to set to `'#'`.

Therefore, `isNaN(alphabet[0])` will always be true.

Therefore, you'll continue to add values into `callcenterList`.

Therefore `i < callcenterList.length` will always be true.

Comment: This is a simple for loop. And there isn't any condition that can create an infinite loop. Even if the "if" condition appears to be wrong, the for loop should continue to iterate. What am I doing wrong in this situation?

Comment: @Yagiz You are adding an element to the iterating array inside the loop with `splice`. Since this is done every time, `i` will never reach the length of the array.

Comment: @Yagiz: I added a more detailed explanation to my answer. Basically, what E_net4 said: you're increasing the length of your array with each iteration, so you'll never reach the end of it.

Comment: It seems reasonable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is hard to believe that length is being re-evaluated, here is a simple example of what problems you might get

Without the break statement, the code will run in an endless loop. (Check the console log for how long the list might be)

```js
var list = [0,1,2,3];

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  list.push(i);
  if (i > 1000) {
    break;
  }
}

console.log( list.length );
```

Your code does exactly the same, except that your splice function will add the new element at the specific position of your list (nl, your index). In the end, it will still increase the length, and your list will be one longer